# Даунгрейд с Windows 10 на Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-10

Всем привет.

В августе поставил апнул десятку с предустановленной на моём ноутбуке восьмёрки, так как восьмёрка мне не нравится. Десятка мне не понравилась ещё больше. Хочу поставить семерку.

У меня есть два раздела на харде, системный с программами и операционкой и "файловый" c игорями и файлами. Первый снесу, второй хотел бы оставить чтобы установить/сохранить многовесящие штуки. Вспомнил, что вроде при установке восьмерки при установленной семерке ОС после установки не видит раздел, если его не форматнуть под определенный формат.

Придется ли мне сносить всё для нормальной работы второго раздела?
Извиняюсь за тавтологию.

Comment: А ты сделай бекап всего, что тебе потом понадобится и, если потом что-то комп не увидит или еще какие-нибудь ошибки вылезут, ты всегда сможешь все данные восстановить.

Comment: @Андрей Курулёв , дело в том, что негде бэкап всего это добра хранить

Comment: тогда действительно нужно выяснять... В любом случае, без бекапа лучше не делать,  ибо опасно потерять данные.

Comment: По идее, должно нормально ставиться... Но не знаю.

Answer (score 1):

Да, придётся. Чтобы поставить Windows 7 и более ранние версии, нужна схема разбиения дисков MBR, для Windows 8+ - GPT. Разница хорошо описана здесь: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-gpt/
Основная разница между схемами в максимально поддерживаемом размере диска, а также в структуре хранения данных.

В итоге, установщик Windows 7 вообще не разрешит устанавливать ОС на диск с Windows 10, потому что он заведомо разбит через GPT.

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность).

Comment: Возможность установки на MBR и GPT зависят от BIOS/UEFI, а не от версии Windows.